# Creating directive in angular that formats the value entered on keypress

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular10

I was trying to create a directive in angular10 that would format the value being displayed while typing in an input type `number` (or even `text`) element.

The desired scenario is that whenever a user presses the "1" in keyboard the text box view should show (in the pipe mentioned below the 1 is transformed to १)

[image]

I have already created a pipe that takes the text and converts into the desired format. But I want the directive to change the viewed data on every keypress event but still retain the actual value as the value entered, only the text displayed to the user must be formatted.

(PS: I already have an idea regarding how to implement the pipe but if required can provide the code for it)

Comment: Try to make your pipe impure, https://angular.io/guide/pipes. 
@Pipe({
  name: 'impurePipeName',
  pure: false
})

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve is basically to mask the displayed value, exactly like `<input type="password"` does. The only thing is that's handled by the browser, so it can get a bit tricky to achieve that from JS/Angular.

But it's still possible. With the note that since you're masking digits with chars, the input needs to be of type="text", otherwise it won't accept the masked chars. Here's how you could do it:

### maskInput.directive.ts

```js
import { Directive, Input, OnInit, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[maskInput]'
})
export class MaskInputDirective implements OnInit {

  readonly TransformTable = {
    0: 'o',
    1: 'a',
    2: 'b',
    3: 'c',
    4: 'd',
    5: 'e',
    6: 'f',
    7: 'g',
    8: 'h',
    9: 'i'
  };

  @Input() maskInput: any;
  @Output() maskInputChange = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const elem = this.el.nativeElement;

    elem.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
      elem.value += this.TransformTable[e.key];

      // just for good measure
      if (this.maskInput === null || this.maskInput === undefined) {
        this.maskInput = '';
      }

      this.maskInputChange.emit(this.maskInput += e.key);

      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    });
  }

}
```

### test.component.ts

```js
export class TestComponent {

  actualValue: any;

}
```

### test.component.html

```html
<input type="text" [(maskInput)]="actualValue">
<div>Original value: {{actualValue}}</div>
```

---

Working solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-isjziu?file=src%2Fapp%2FmaskInput.directive.ts